# Laravel Sign in Singout issue when clicking back button

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I am implementing a basic login logout functionality with one extra controller just to check the accessibility of pages for logged in user. When I am logged in and I click on  back button I get redirected to page where I start seeing Register and Login button on top right corner that suggests that I am logged out. But I am still able to click the nav links which are suppose to be only accessed by logged in user only. Below is the code snippet.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {

    Route::get('/', function () {
            return view('welcome');
    }); 
    Route::resource('notices', 'NoticesController');

    Route::auth();

});
```

My controller

```
class NoticesController extends Controller
{
    //
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}

    public function index()
    {
        return 'hello world';
    }
}
```

snippet of blade file:

```
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="app-navbar-collapse">
                <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="{{ url('/notices') }}">Home</a></li>
                </ul>

                <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <!-- Authentication Links -->
                    @if (Auth::guest())
                        <li><a href="{{ url('/login') }}">Login</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{{ url('/register') }}">Register</a></li>
                    @else
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                                {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>

                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li><a href="{{ url('/logout') }}"><i class="fa fa-btn fa-sign-out"></i>Logout</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    @endif
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I do not want the /notices route to be accessible when my Register and LogIn options are visible on top right corner. Kindly help.

Comment: Pressing the back button will not do a sign out action.

Comment: Then why I start seeing "Register and Log In option on the top right corner" Please help.

Comment: Blame browser cache. http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: You are correct I guess. Because when I explicitly log out the user by clicking on Log out button. Then my home button is not more accessible.

Comment: But we don't see this issue on any real world web sites. How to avoid it. Because it's one of the basic feature. I am new to Laravel. I am sure it can be avoided in some way. can you please guide. And kindly cross check my code snippet too. really appreciate your time.

Comment: I'm not using Laravel, so I can't really check your code snippet. But maybe it solves your issue if you send a `Cache-Control` header which turns of caching in/for all these dynamic sites.

Comment: This may be informative for you https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/how-to-set-headers-in-laraval-no-cache

Answer (score 1):

In the view, before all other things, place this code, it will tell the browser to not cache the page.

```
<?php
header("Expires: Tue, 03 Jul 2001 06:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's browser's cache memory problem. The browser's cache memory store all things. so when we press back button it redirects one step back. I faced it also in my project. But yes, if you want to solve this problem in any particular page then go to through this link:

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/549347/Browser-Back-Button-Issue-After-Logout

Maybe this helps you!